# Is there any other way to connect a Public API with SAP Analytics Cloud?

Tags: odata, sap-analytics-cloud

I am trying to make a connection with the Public API in SAP Analytics Cloud, but unfortunately it is giving me issues. Any way I can resolve this.

[image]